# How to dynamically create dictionaries whose name are taken from the contents of a directory in python?

Tags: python

I have a directories with filenames. I want for each of the files to create a dictionary.I do this:

```
files=glob.glob(*)
for f in files:
    f={}
```

but i don't get the result that i want. I.e: in my directory i have aaa bbb ccc. After the execution of my program i want to have 3 dictionaries. The first aaa={} t second one bbb={} and the 3rd one ccc={}.

Comment: You really need to include an example of what result you're looking for. Right now you're just resetting the variable "f" in your loop to an empty dictionary for each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably want to create a dict to hold all of your other dicts:

```
files = glob.glob('*')
d = {}
for f in files:
    d[f] = {}
```

Now to get access to the dictionary associated with `file1`, you'd just do  `file1_dict = d['file1']`, or you could reference the items inside the that dict directly:  `d['file1']['data1']`

Comment: but i want each dictionary to have the name of the file

Comment: ok you are right. I have what i want with an extra layer of dictionaries

Comment: @curious -- Anytime you want to dynamically set the name of a variable, you should use a dict instead.  You *can* do it by modifying the dictionary returned by `globals`, but you really (**really**) shouldn't.

Comment: @curious, you can think of `d` as a separate namespace. Otherwise what should happen if you have files named "for", "in", "f", etc.

Comment: @gnibbler -- That's a good point.  Another reason that I would avoid it is because getting a handle on a variable you don't know the name of can be a little tricky as well.  As I see it, you ultimately need to resort to using a dictionary (`globals()`) to get the variables names/data anyway -- might as well save yourself the extra step.